# Parse object dot notation to retrieve a value of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm finding myself struggling with a little problem. 
Let's say I've got an object:

```
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: true
    }
};
```

Now I also have a String `'foo.bar.baz'`. I'd now like to retrieve the value from the object using the string.

Please note: This is just an example, the solution needs to be dynamic.

**Update:**

I need the variable name also to be dynamic and parsed from the string. Also I can't be sure that my variable is a property of the window.

I have already built a solution using `eval`, but this is pretty ugly I think:
http://jsfiddle.net/vvzyX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
function getValue(namespace, parent) {
    var parts = namespace.split('.'),
        current = parent || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
        if (current[parts[i]]) {
            current = current[parts[i]];
        } else {
          if (i >= parts.length - 1)
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: true
    }
};
console.log(getValue('foo.bar.baz')); //true
```

The first argument of the function is the namespace (dot separated values) and the second one is the `parent` object, if parent is not provided then `window` is used.

One more example using the parent argument:

```
var str = 'foo.bar.baz';
    foo = {
       bar: {
          baz: true
       }
    };

result = getValue(str, foo);
console.log(result);
```

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvzyX/2/).

Similar approach is used in YUI. Their approach is called Namespace pattern. The main benefit is simulation of packages/namespaces. The only difference between this script and the namespace pattern is that the namespace function creates nested structure instead of only returning value.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece. The variable only can be either in the parent scope or in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

For example,

```
function get(obj, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function(obj, p) {
        return obj[p]
    }, obj);
}
```

Demo:

```
tree = {
    foo: {
        bar: 1,
        baz: { quux: 3 },
    },
    spam: 1
}

console.log(get(tree, 'foo.baz.quux')) // 3
```

Comment: @thg435: Lol no! See my answer.

Comment: @Amberlamps:  "I can't be sure that my variable is a property of the window"

Comment: This is excellent.  I've adapted it for use in Angular event delegation here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32797911/237913

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var name = [window].concat('foo.bar.baz'.split('.')).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev[curr];
});

console.log(name);

// -> 'true'
```

Comment: interesting but I cannot get it to work properly, somehow prev[curr] is not accepted: http://jsfiddle.net/VXeaa/

Comment: You are not using my original code. You missed `[window].concat([...])` in your code example.

Comment: This is copy-pasted from your example, still no good in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/VXeaa/2/

Comment: JsFiddle runs its code in a local scope, therefore `foo` is not global. As a result `window["foo"]` is undefined. This code only works if your object is globally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is using string split to split that string into an array first, and access the object via `[]` to access the attribute of that object with a loop