# Javascript dynamic function calls with namespace

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, eval

Whereas using `eval` is not a good programming practice. This question is for didactic nature, or to learn a better solution:

See the following example in Javascript:

```
var foo = foo || {};
foo.bar = function(str) { alert(str); };

foo.bar('aaa'); // trigger alert('aaa')
window['foo']['bar']('bbb'); // trigger alert('bbb')
```

I'm searching for an generic caller to work with `foo.bar('str')`, `foo.nestedObj.bar(params)`, `foo.n2.n[1..99].bar(params)`

Thats because I can't call something like:

```
param = [5,2,0];
call = 'foo.bar';
window[call](param); // not work
```

But I can call function using eval:

```
param = [5,2,0];
call = 'foo.bar'
eval(call + '(param)'); // works
```

How can I do this **WITHOUT** `eval`?

Comment: This is asked almost every day. Just wait a minute, looking for the dupes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14375753/989121

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it evil to use eval to convert a string to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396647/is-it-evil-to-use-eval-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function)

Comment: The dupe I linked too has a list of other dupes included.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
callback = "foo.bar";
var p = callback.split('.'),
c = window; // "parent || window" not working in my tests of linked examples
for (var i in p) {
    if (c[p[i]]) {
        c = c[p[i]];
    } 
}
c('aaa');
```

And this solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have answered this before, but here it goes again:

```
function genericFunction(path) {

    return [window].concat(path.split('.')).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev[curr];
    });

}

var param = [5, 2, 0];
var foo = { bar: function(param) { return param.length; } };

genericFunction('foo.bar')(param);

// => 3
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. Just link to your previous post and cast a closevote.

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate answer. I modified and improved this one.

Comment: It might be a better option to edit the original one by improving it and providing a link. Also your answer doesn't provide any explanation. I would like to know why that function works.