# Syntax wrong for onclick event on string template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

The `onclick` event on the return template doesn't do anything

```js
{
    field: '',
    title: '',
    width: '80px',
    template: function (record) {
        return (
            '  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-xs btn-success margin-top-5 margin-bottom-5 btn-lg, btn-sucess"  ng-class="btnClass" ng-click="console.log(record)"> <span>Add</span> </a>'
        );
    }
},
```

Tried changing the string of the `a` tag, still unable to call `ng-click` method.

Comment: Where and how is this object used?

Comment: Perhaps [delegation is an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965627/angular-ng-click-event-delegation)

Comment: @mplungjan is is used part of a bigger object for options on a kendo grid

Comment: I suggested delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "`javascript:void(0)`" which is a function in JavaScript that returns undefined.
When you click it it wont do anything. Just change `href="#"`
Also update the ng-click to prevent default:

```
href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();console.log(record)"
```

For more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: so is the ngClick not necessary , can I add a console log at the href

Comment: You can use that, but make sure to remove javascript:void(0) because it overrides ng-click. Or just use href="#"

Comment: still not working

Comment: appologies how can I make something like this work '<button ng-Click="console.log("someString")">test</button>'

Comment: having trouble with where to add the quotation marks

Comment: try like this, href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();console.log(record)"